# The simpleType 'Infinite' has already been declared

Tags: asp.net, web-config, visual-studio-2015

I am in visual studio 2015 (ASP.NET web forms project) and I am seeing the following warning signs in the web.config file,

[image]

I am not sure how to fix this warning. Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: There also seems to be a squiggly line under the `y` of `<system.web.extensions>`. Are you sure the XML is valid?

Comment: Yes, it is valid. I am seeing this warning all of a sudden and recently I have not made any changes to it.